# DataTable.AsEnumerable().Where() vs DataTable.Select()

Tags: c#, performance, linq, datatable

We've been querying data in the `DataTable` in Linq mode, and we've never had any performance issues. Until the following case, it takes 600s+ with Linq, but it takes only 3s with `DataTable.Select()`. The results are consistent. Intuition tells me that Linq shouldn’t be so slow, and there is something wrong with my operation, but I don’t know how to improve it, can anyone give me some advice?

`GetDtTest_Base()` and `GetDtTest_Info()` are `DataTable` and `DataSet` returned from Sql Server through `SqlDataAdapter` in ADO.NET.

```
DataTable dtBase = GetDtTest_Base();  //4W rows
DataSet dsInfo = GetDtTest_Info();    //two Datatable  4W rows, 2K rows

//Normally, we use Linq all the time. In this scenario, it takes about 600 seconds to query through Linq
foreach (DataRow item in dtBase.Rows)
{
    string pnum = item["pnum"].ToString();
    string number = item["number"].ToString();

    var query_Info1 = dsInfo.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
        .Where(w => w.Field<string>("pnum") == pnum && w.Field<string>("calleee164") == number)
        .Select(s => s);
    item["conn"] = query_Info1.Count() > 0 ? (query_Info1.First())["conn"] : 0;
    item["total"] = query_Info1.Count() > 0 ? (query_Info1.First())["total"] : 0;

    var query_Info2 = dsInfo.Tables[1].AsEnumerable()
        .Where(w => w.Field<string>("pnum") == pnum && w.Field<string>("calleee164") == number)
        .Select(s => s);
    item["asCnt"] = query_Info2.Count() > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    item["asTrunks"] = query_Info2.Count() > 0 ? (query_Info2.First())["trunks"] : null;
}

//After changing this query, it only took 3 seconds to query
foreach (DataRow item in dtBase.Rows)
{
    string pnum = item["pnum"].ToString();
    string number = item["number"].ToString();

    DataRow[] query_Info1 = dsInfo.Tables[0].Select($"pnum='{pnum}' and calleee164='{number}'");
    if (query_Info1 != null && query_Info1.Length >= 1)
    {
        item["conn"] = query_Info1[0]["conn"].ToString();
        item["total"] = query_Info1[0]["total"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        item["conn"] = 0;
        item["total"] = 0;
    }

    DataRow[] query_Info2 = dsInfo.Tables[1].Select($"pnum='{pnum}' and calleee164='{number}'");
    if (query_Info2 != null && query_Info2.Length >= 1)
    {
        item["asCnt"] = 1;
        item["asTrunks"] = query_Info2[0]["trunks"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        item["asCnt"] = 0;
        item["asTrunks"] = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to move `dsInfo.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()` outside the `foreach` loop as that may create the overhead.

Comment: var query_Info10 = dsInfo.Tables[0].AsEnumerable();
var query_Info20 = dsInfo.Tables[1].AsEnumerable();
foreach (DataRow item in dtBase.Rows)
{
    ... ...
    var query_Info1 = query_Info10
        .Where... ...
}

the problem still exists

Comment: You're querying both data tables 4 times per iteration, Count and First, twice, while the same thing can be done in one `FirstOrDefault()` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative approach is to create a structure designed for lookups.

Original approach will iterate `dsInfo` tables for every row in `dtBase`, which is O(n*m). With lookup data structure finding row from `dsInfo` tables will be one operation, which makes O(n).

```
var base = GetDtTest_Base();
var infoSet = GetDtTest_Info();

var firstLookup = info[0].AsEnumerable()
    .ToLookup(row => (Num: row.Field<string>("pnum"), Callee: row.Field<string>("calleee164")));
var secondLookup = info[1].AsEnumerable()
    .ToLookup(row => (Num: row.Field<string>("pnum"), Callee: row.Field<string>("calleee164")));

foreach (DataRow item in dtBase.Rows)
{
    var pnum = item["pnum"].ToString();
    var number = item["number"].ToString();
    var key = (Num: pnum, Callee: number);

    item["conn"] = firstLookup[key].Select(row => row.Field<int>("conn")).FirstOrDefault();
    item["total"] = firstLookup[key].Select(row => row.Field<int>("total")).FirstOrDefault();

    item["asCnt"] = secondLookup[key].Any() ? 1 : 0;
    item["asTrunks"] = secondLookup[key].Select(row => row.Field<string>("trunks")).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, although I still don't quite understand why the above writing is very slow, I used .ToList() after the query still has no effect, but your writing is really efficient, thank you very very much.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a grave dig, but recently hit performance issues with `DataTable.AsEnumerable()...` in old code that was resolved by converting to `DataTable.AsEnumerable().ToList()...`.

+1 for Fabio's answer, definitely a cleaner more efficient approach, but if you don't want to mess too much with legacy code and profiling shows a hotpath in your linq query, try converting to a list and see how you go.